# How does the Archive Manager handle temporary files?

Tags: archive, compression, rar

Suppose I have a password protected compressed file, lets call it `file.rar`. It contains a video file, lets call `video.mp4`.

I open `file.mp4` with Archive Manager, enter the required password and double click on `video.mp4`. Since I've not explicitly extracted the `video.mp4` file, I assume the AM extracts it temporarily in a certain location and opens it with associated program (i.e vlc).

**Where is this temp file stored? Does the Archive Manager ever delete the temp file? And if so, when does the AM delete the file?**

Answer (score 0):

The temporary files created by the Archive Manager are found in the `~/.cache` folder inside folders prefixed by `.fr-`. They look something like `.fr-rdbA4t/`, `.fr-zPtx02/` ...etc.